# I pressed 'vote up' two times for a comment, now voting option is not available

Tags: support, comments, upvotes, comment-votes

I pressed two times on ''vote-up', and now I cannot vote a good comment because the option is blocked, is to still be able to vote up the comment?

Comment: It's strange that you didn't get any confirmation when you pressed it the second time...

Answer (score 5):

Once you have taken back your up-vote on a comment (that is, undoing the up-vote by pressing up-arrow twice), you cannot up-vote the comment again. This is by-design. Reason is mentioned on [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032):

> We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.

Before you can undo the vote, system will show this confirmation box:

> [image]

This makes sure that you are making a conscious decision. As a result, you cannot upvote that particular comment again.

Comment: Strange, I didn't get this message, and I was not sure that I voted up so I miss-clicked..

Comment: That reason is just another way of saying that you can't undo because "we don't want you to".

Comment: I didn't receive a notification but my undo of my up-vote was due to a mis-click. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471531/is-there-a-more-terse-way-to-map-properties-of-one-object-to-another-in-es6-es20?noredirect=1#comment58661845_35471531